# SQL: change query to fully nested query

Tags: sql

#SQL Please help change to fully nested query. Thanks.

/*
Q12: Write the fully nested query to display the guest number (guests on horseback), city and state of all guests
who reserved a horseback riding activity in June and July of 2019.
*/

I just write the script by using join. But I don't know how to change the way to fully nested query.

```
select g.guest# "guests on horseback", g.city, g.state
    from guests g
        inner join reservations r
            on g.guest# = r.guest#
                inner join activities a
                    on r.aid = a.aid
                        where a.type='horseback'
                            and
                            month(r.rdate) in (6,7)
                                and year(r.rdate) =2019 
                                order by 1;
```

Please help. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTKUe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhepd.png)

expected output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HkLw.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is a fully nested query? Something like that?

```
select g.guest#, g.city, g.state 
from guests g
where g.guest# in
(
  select r.guest#
  from reservations r 
  where year(r.rdate) = 2019
  and month(r.rdate) in (6, 7)
  and r.aid in
  (
    select a.aid
    from activities a
    where a.type = 'horseback'
  )
)
order by g.guest#;
```